# Creation of a functor inside a member function without taking the class as a argument

Tags: c++, boost, bind, functor

Apologies for the cryptic decryption.

I wish to create a functor of the following type:

```
const boost::function<bool ()>& functor
```

Please consider the class:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
class X { 
    public:
        bool foo();
        void bar() ;
};

void X::bar() {
    const boost::function<bool (X *)>& f = &X::foo;
}

bool X::foo() {
    std::cout << __func__ << " " << __LINE__ << " " << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

I have:

```
const boost::function<bool (X *)>& f = &X::foo;
```

Can I have something like

```
const boost::function<bool ()>& f = &X::foo;
```

with boost::bind or something else ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using const references to a boost function?  Reference lifetime extension will usually work, but it seems pointlessly fragile to create an alias to a temporary object instead of an actual object?

Comment: @Yakk agreed. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-static member function must be called with an object. Thus, you must always implicitly pass `this` pointer as its argument.

You can accomplish this with `boost::bind`:

```
const boost::function<bool()>& f = boost::bind(&X::foo, this);
```

Comment: Additional Information: using this technique implies that the object (*this) will exist longer than the function object (f).  It is a common idiom to insure this by using a boost::shared_ptr<X> as the argument rather than this.

Comment: Hi @Dale,
Thanks. I was trying to do this through :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856388/accessing-shared-ptr-for-this-pointer